# Getting data from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
Select name, surname from student
```

and I can't get data with VB.Net.
My code is:

```
Dim reader As SqlDataReader
With dbCmd
    .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    .CommandText = "sp_myPersonalSP"
End With
reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader()
```

But Visual Studio send me an exception when it try "reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader()":

> Procedure sp_myPersonalSP has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

Thanks! I am a newbie in VB.Net :-(

Comment: Procedure sp_myPersonalSP_Ruoli has no parameters and arguments were supplied

Comment: Which error you are getting?

Comment: Hi @Emdad, my error is: "Procedure sp_myPersonalSP has no parameters and arguments were supplied."
My store-procedure is like this: "Create myPersonalSP AS select name, surname from student" no other text in my sp.

Comment: The error message suggests you have added parameters to the command but I see none in your VB.NET code snippet. Separately' you should not use the `sp_` prefix to name stored procedures as that is used to denote system procs.

Comment: Ok, but how I can get data (name1, surname1, name2, surname2, ...) from my store procedure? Thanks!

Comment: To get the first row, invoke `reader.Read()` after `dbCmd.ExecuteReader()` and then get column values via the reader,

Comment: Have you used the same instance of `dbCmd` earlier in the code and added parameters to it? If so, you could call `.Dispose()` on the earlier instance and then instantiate a new one, or use `dbCmd.Parameters.Clear()`.

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Just guessing here but since you didn't declare dbCmd in the code you posted I am suspecting you used that command already on a previous database call. As such the parameters would still be added to that command. This leads me to question if you are handling your database objects correctly across the board.

Answer (score 0):

A function that returns a datatable from Sql Server executing a stored procedure:

```
Public Function GetApplicationType() As DataTable
    Dim MyDataTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
    ' The connection string information is in the web.config file - see below
    Dim con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnectionString").ToString()
    Dim MyDataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("GetSomeData", con)
    MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    ' add the parameters in the same order and type as what the stored procedure expects, they must match the names in  the stored procedure and are case sensitive.

    MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParameterName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10));
    MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Parametername2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40));

    MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@ParameterName"].Value = somedata1;
    MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@ParameterName2"].Value = somedata2;

    MyDataAdapter.Fill(MyDataTable)
    Return MyDataTable
End Function
```

web.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="server=192.168.11.11;database=Test;uid=someusername; pwd=somepassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to add the parameters in the same order with SQL Sever. It is necessary in Access.

Answer (score 0):

You can display your query results in a DataGridView. You need to have a connection for the command to execute. Open the connection before you execute the command. The Using...End Using statements with ensure that your objects are closed and disposed event if there is an error.

```
Private Sub GetData()
            Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your Connection String")
                Using dbCmd As New SqlCommand
                    With dbCmd
                        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                        .CommandText = "sp_myPersonalSP"
                        .Connection = cn
                    End With
                    cn.Open()
                    Using reader As SqlDataReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader()
                        'You can view the result of your query in a DataGridView
                        Dim dt As New DataTable
                        dt.Load(reader)
                        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

to retrieve data from stored procedure, just call your stored procedure name like this.

Dim stringquery = "CALL YOURSTOREDPROCNAME()"

Try my Code:

```
        Dim dt as new Datatable
        con.Open()
        Dim query = "Call StoredProcedureName()"
        command = New SqlCommand(query, con)
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        dt.Clear()
        adapter.Fill(dt)
        con.Close()
```

-KEVIN